# Clear div and load new div with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, transition

I'm building a webapp in ASP.NET and am trying to get a button (a Panel) to load a "window" or sub application to add new users. I want the div holding the buttons to transitionally clear or be "deleted" and in the same window, load the corresponding application/div. Most people suggest Ajax but none of the answers I've found have the desired effect I want. Below is a sample of the button/panel item which is contained in a div that is 100% vh and 100% vw. I'm not exactly familiar with jQuery either which doesn't help.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="admin-panel">
            <div class="row admin-controls">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" >
                        <div class="admin-control-item" onclick=""><!-- This is the button to load the application -->
                             <i class="material-icons md-48">people</i>
                             <h3>Current Users</h3>
                         </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </div>
...
</div>
```

Comment: Update: An example of some transition effects I'm trying to accomplish can be seen here:

[link](https://material.io/guidelines/motion/transforming-material.html#transforming-material-radial-transformation)

Comment: what about creating two divs and toggle their display values?

Comment: Doesn't that reduce the efficiency by adding additional html for each and every button?